# sklearn Pipeline correct usage

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have a dataframe in python and it has datetime filed called 'datetime'. Using Pipeline and  FeatureUnion i am trying to extract day,month,weekday and isBusinessday. In order to extract those features i have written custom code.

I am using the following code to extract day,month,weekday and isBusinessday

```
class itemselector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.key]

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self


    f_df = Pipeline([

       ('union', FeatureUnion([
    ('date', Pipeline([
        ('sitem', itemselector('pickup_datetime')),
        ('sday', Extract_date()),
    ])),
    ('month', Pipeline([
        ('sitem', itemselector('pickup_datetime')),
        ('smonth', Extract_month()),
    ])),
])),

    ])
```

When i run this code i am getting list as a output. Say for example :

```
df = f_df.fit_transform(df_train[:5])
```

output :

```
[14 12 19  6 26  3  6  1  4  3]  // it has both day and month.  it is not expected output
```

But i was both day and month to be seperate features. How can i do that ? What went wrong in my code ?  Can some one help me to find it ?

**UPDATE**

to summarise my problem, I am getting output shape `(10,)` but i want my output to be `(5,2)`

**Updated 1** as per the request i have added necessary code

```
class Extract_date(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X):
        print('one')
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X.apply(lambda y: y.day)


class Extract_month(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, **atr):
        print('two')
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X.apply(lambda y: y.month)
```

Comment: To those who downvoted, please leave a comment and down vote

Comment: FeatureUnion will horizontally stack the data coming from each part of the internal transformers. Can you show what `Extract_month` and `Extract_date` returns?

Comment: @VivekKumar,  I have added necessary code.  Please have a look on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the `Extract_month` and `Extract_date` return a Series which is a 1-d vector, hence the FeatureUnion is not correctly stacking them. For FeatureUnion you need 2-d data with same number of rows from each internal transformer.

You can use `reshape(-1,1)` for this.

So change your methods like this:

```
class Extract_date(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    ...
    ...

    def transform(self, X):
        return X.apply(lambda y: y.day).values.reshape(-1,1)


class Extract_month(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    ...
    ...

    def transform(self, X):
        return X.apply(lambda y: y.month).values.reshape(-1,1)
```

Now the output should be correct. Feel free to ask if still any problem.